# binary patch in C (instead of xxd)

Tags: c, binary, hex

I've been writing shell scripts (to make things easier to use) but this time i wanted to do it in C, and one command that i used the most is `xxd -r`, to "patch" a binary file.

Exemple :

```
echo "0000050: 2034" | xxd -r - my_binary_file
```

My question is : is there a way to do something similar in C ?

(I hope my question is clear)

Answer (score 0):

Universally, you could use [fopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) (with "w" on Unix and "wb" on Windows), [fseek](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fseek), and [fwrite](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite).

Of if you prefer posix style, [open](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open), [seek](https://linux.die.net/man/2/seek), and [write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

On Win32, the posix equivalents are [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew), [SetFilePointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer), and [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile)

Comment: If you use `fopen()`, you must use `"rb+"` to avoid truncating the file.

Comment: like `FILE *fd = fopen(my_binary_file, "rb+");` → `fseek(fd, 0, 0x10);` → `fwrite(??, ??, 1, fd);`

Comment: `fseek(fd, 0x50, SEEK_SET)`

Comment: I don't want to deprive you of a learning opportunity.  But you got the general idea. Open the file, pass the file handle to fseek, write the byte or bytes at that address.  Don't forget to call fclose.  (posix: close, win32:CloseHandle).  And always be checking return values for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could still use your command and call it in C code using system() function.

system("echo "0000050: 2034" | xxd -r - my_binary_file")

NOTE: you can dynamically build above string with file name and parameters using sprintf() function and then pass it to the system function() as shown below.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char acBuffer[512]; //Allocate as reuiquired only
    memset(acBuffer, 0x00, sizeof(acBuffer));

    sprintf(acBuffer, "echo \"%s\" | xxd -r - %s", "0000050: 2034", "YourBinaryFile");
    system(acBuffer); //You can check the return type if you want to

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but if i could avoid using `system()` it would be cool (else it's not really C)